# Serving multiple root directories in Apache

Tags: apache, drupal

I would like my two sites: flowers.loc (Drupal 8) and honey.loc (Drupal 7) sites to work locally on Apache (v: 2.234).

First directory for flowers.loc:

```
Sites/drupal8/docroot
```

Second directory for honey.loc:

```
Sites/drupal7/docroot
```

I have this setting in httpd, apache configuration file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
  DocumentRoot /User/Vizzaro/Sites

  <Directory "/User/Vizzaro/Sites">
  Options FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: So set up a proper VirtualHost for each domain …?

Comment: Yes, how would I serve or use Alias?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html to find out how to set up virtual hosts. Your configuration file has only one virtual host entry but you need one entry for each site. And furthermore your config is missing the ServerName. Try this: (untested)

```
# Ensure that Apache listens on port 80
Listen 80

# Listen for virtual host requests on all IP addresses
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName flowers.loc
    DocumentRoot /User/Vizzaro/Sites/drupal8/docroot

    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName honey.loc
    DocumentRoot /User/Vizzaro/Sites/drupal7/docroot

    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>
```

And be sure that honey.loc and flowers.loc both point to the IP of the machine on wich your apache is running. Try `ping flowers.loc` - if this results in an error like `Name or service not known` you probably have to edit your hosts file to fix it.

Comment: Thanks, Ralf. This works but how about a 443? For some reason, multiple docroots didn't work for me in the httpd-ssl conf file for two different docroots.